# Update multiple rows with radio button check

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am getting the value for the single tsid for each record, however the checked radio button value is not returned in the array, I just get 0? Any help is appreciated.

PHP:

```
// Set the timesheets to set status approved/rejected
// find out how many records there are to update
$size = count($_POST['tsid']);

// start a loop in order to update each record
$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
// define each variable
$tsid = intval($_POST['tsid'][$i]);
$personnelid = intval($_POST['personnel'][$i]);
print "TSID: " . $tsid . "<br>";
print "TSuser: " . $personnelid . "<br>";
if ($tsid > 0 && $personnelid > 0) {
// do the update and print out some info just to provide some visual feedback
$query = "Update timesheets set status='1' where id= '$tsid' LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
}
++$i;
}
mysql_close();
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tsid[]" value="<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>">
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <a href="tsapprove.php?id=<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>"><p><?PHP echo $row['personnel']; ?></p>
    <p><?PHP echo $row['name']; ?></p>
    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong><?PHP echo $row['totalhrs']; ?> H</strong></p>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="radio" name="personnel[]" id="1" value="<?PHP echo $row['personnel']; ?>"  />
      <label for="1">Approve</label>
      <input type="radio" name="personnel[]" id="2" value="<?PHP echo $row['personnel']; ?>"  />
      <label for="2">Reject</label>
    </fieldset>
</a>
<a href="tsapprove.php?id=<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>">View Details</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What part returns 0? Is it $size, $i or tsid?

Comment: After data-role="fieldcontain", did you mean <a href=" and not <a href"?

Comment: Its the radio button value personnel I get nothing back on. TSID returns correctly.

Comment: the href is a trick for css, thats correct. JQM sees the whole li as a link otherwise. Im just setting the css overlay by not setting the =

Comment: Larry, $personnelid = intval($_POST['personnel'][$i]); returns 0

Comment: ok, don't quite get why it would return 0.  But, if im following you correctly...  There's kind of an issue with  this....   

Say theres two items, this is the what is posted:

tsid[0]
personnel[0]
personnel[1]

tsid[1]
personnel[2]
personnel[3]

So when you loop through tsid[1], 1 being $i - its grabing personnel (Reject) from tsid[0]

I could totally be on the wrong path here, but still examining =)

Comment: Larry, basically I dont care what they selected on accept or reject, I just want to know something was chosen for that radio select. It returns the tsid just fine, but when checking for any value with personnel from the radio button, it returns 0 every time for the value. FYI: Printing out the values: TSID: 3
TSuser: 0
TSID: 1
TSuser: 0
TSID: 2
TSuser: 0

Comment: @JamesFerguson Posting just your PHP code isn't very nice since I'm not a PHP Parser :). Could you please post the HTML output that the browser sees? As-in, go to the page in a browser, then click "View Source," then copy/paste the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you can piece this together:

```
<?

$size = count($_POST['tsid']);

echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
  $tsid = $_POST['tsid'][$i];
  $pid = $_POST['personnel_'.$i];


  print "TSID: " . $tsid . "<br />";
  print "TSuser: " . $pid . "<br />";

  $i++;
}

?>
<form method="post">
<!--tsid[0] - $i = 0-->
<input type="hidden" name="tsid[]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="personnel_0" value="111" />
<input type="radio" name="personnel_0" value="222" />

<!--tsid[1] - $i = 1-->
<input type="hidden" name="tsid[]" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="personnel_1" value="333" />
<input type="radio" name="personnel_1" value="444" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Basically, the way you are returning personnel doesnt really work.   So I simplified this a bit, and basically set the radios for personnel differently.  Instead of an array, its setting the actual name with the TSID value.

I hard coded 1 and 2, but you would replace with your $row['id'], as well has the number after "personnel_" would be 0..1..2 etc

Hopefully this helps

edit: few issues with code

Comment: Ok, I think I figured the issue. In JQM if I disable their CSS classes, it works as expected. However when turned on, the radios are ignored. The docs show doing something like this: 
Just unsure how to send that to PHP for updating the form properly.
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('input[name=personnel]:checked', '#ts').val()
</script>